# How to save tags locally to device?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to save tags with local storage. It doesn't work and I don't know what's going on with it.

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.tags = [
    { text: 'Tag1' },
    { text: 'Tag2' },
    { text: 'Tag3' }
  ];
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/css/ng-tags-input.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.15"></script>
    <script src="http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/js/ng-tags-input.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <tags-input ng-model="tags"></tags-input>
    <p>Model: {{tags}}</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

I'm attempting to do this with localStorage to have the tags stay there when the user leaves the app, goes back to another page, or just refreshes it.

```
window.localStorage['name'] = {{tags}};
```

Link to doc:
http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/

Comment: What doesn't work and where in the code is the localStorage assignment? Would using  `window.localStorage['name'] = $scope.tags` instead help?

Comment: @MattZeunert: also, I imagine, one needs to _read_ localStorage upon startup to see if something is persisted there already.

Comment: I put it right after $scope.tags in app.js.

Is there another place I should put it? (Sorry I'm new to angular)

Comment: Putting it there seems fine to me and should set a value. I'm confused about the `{{tags}}` in your JavaScript code though. Is that actually in your JS or is `{{tags}}` just a placeholder for something else?

Comment: actual javascript @MattZeunert

Answer (score 1):

You need to save tags model to localStorage and update it on every collection change: remove/add tags. It is convenient to create helper service for this:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, storage) {
    $scope.tags = storage.get('tags') || [
        { text: 'Tag1' },
        { text: 'Tag2' },
        { text: 'Tag3' }
    ];

    $scope.$watchCollection('tags', function(tags) {
        storage.set('tags', tags);
    });
});

app.factory('storage', function() {
    return {
        get: function(key) {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage[key] || 'null');
        },
        set: function(key, value) {
            window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
        }
    };
});
```

Note, how in controller code you first check stored items and if not available fallback to default tags:

```
$scope.tags = storage.get('tags') || [
    { text: 'Tag1' },
    { text: 'Tag2' },
    { text: 'Tag3' }
];
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/jgJNADUuTsgbTNvK16Jg?p=preview

Comment: The demo works fine for me. As for `$scope.$watchCollection` - it is available since version 1.1.x. What version are you using?

Comment: Can you copy error message from console? There is also a link to  error description.

Comment: I fixed all the bugs. everything is in there. but it's still not saving the tags.

I am not getting any errors though. @djsq 

Since this is Ionic, the factory is in services.js  - do you think because it's in another file, it is affecting it?

Comment: It should not matter as soon as `storage` service is loaded. To test it check dev tools -> Resources tab -> Local storage.

Comment: Okay, it's not appearing in local storage when I add a tag. I moved the service around too in case and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hm, it's hard to tell. You say there are no errors but localStorage is not populated? Also `console.log(localStorage.tags)` is `undefined`? Try to put a debugger into `$scope.$watchCollection` and see if it's hit.

Answer (score 0):

This code will read the tags from localStorage, put it inside of the controller

```
$scope.tags = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['tags'] || '[]');
```

This code will save the tags into localStorage:

```
window.localStorage['tags'] = JSON.stringify($scope.tags);
```

For example, you controller will be like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.tags = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['tags'] || '[]');

  //Another methods
});
```